# Superposition principle and affine functions: why does it hold only if $\alpha + \beta = 1$ in $f(\alpha \vec{x} + \beta \vec{y})$?

Tags: linear-algebra

An affine function $f$ mapping $R^n$ to $R^m$ is defined as $f(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x} + \vec{b}$.

Our book tells us that the superposition principle holds for affine functions only if $\alpha + \beta = 1$ in the following expression:

$f(\alpha \vec{x} + \beta \vec{y}) = A(\alpha \vec{x} + \beta \vec{y}) + \vec{b} = \alpha f(\vec{x}) + \beta f(\vec{y}) + \vec{b}$

I don't see why we need the condition that $\alpha + \beta = 1$ for this to be true.

Could someone help me verify why that's true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct expression is
$$
f(\alpha \vec{x} + \beta \vec{y}) = A(\alpha \vec{x} + \beta \vec{y}) + \vec{b} = 
\alpha A\vec{x} + \beta A\vec{y} + \vec{b}=\alpha f(\vec{x}) + \beta f(\vec{y}) + (1-\alpha-\beta)\vec{b}.
$$
Now it is clear that for the superposition principle to hold the last term must be zero.

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused. Where did the $(1 - \alpha - \beta)$ come from?

Comment: Oh... $\alpha A \vec{x}$ is not just $f(\vec{x})$! It's $f(\vec{x}) - \vec{b}$.